# Ideals contained in a field not algebraically closed are not comaximal

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, affine-geometry, affine-varieties

[image]

My question is: why must $b$ be $1$? Also why can't there be $ax+y^2$ as polynomials?

Comment: [Images of text and mathematical expressions are discouraged here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged). Please take the time to typeset your post using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: $b=1$ to get the constant coefficient of the polynomial on the left-hand side to match the constant coefficient of the polynomial on the right-hand side.  Then, subtracting these $1$s, the result is that $ax+y^2$ is the $0$ polynomial, which is evidently false.

Comment: @EricTowers thanks for the quick reply. Could you say why $ax+y^2$ cannot be zero polynomials?

Comment: There is only one zero polynomial -- all its coefficients are zero.